# Ensure memory mapped page is in memory

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a read-only Win32 memory mapped file with no sharing open. Is there any way to tell Windows to load some page into memory, making sure that it was loaded successfully, and keep it in memory until I release it?

The reason I want this is because reading from memory mapped memory can throw an exception in case the page can't be loaded because of disk/network failure. Handling this case everywhere in code is impractical, so I would like to ensure that at least some block is safe to read, and then read block by block.

I know of `PrefetchVirtualMemory` but that's strictly a performance optimization; it doesn't guarantee that the pages will successfully load or still be in memory when I get to reading them.

P.S. I don't necessarily want to prevent paging, paging is fine. My main concern are network drives. So `VirtualLock` doesn't seem like the right thing.

Comment: Are you mixing languages?  You tagged both C and C++.  I recommend against mixing them.Things like inheritance and function overloading make interfacing more difficult.  Also, a lot of the Window's API is in the C language.  Note: C and C++ are distinct languages (C++ has inheritance, C doesn't).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know, but it's irrelevant since I'm asking about the Win32 API. I'm just tagging them because I don't want responses using some wrappers, like the c# library or something like that.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. First you are saying that you want page to be in memory, then you seem to want paging...

Comment: Since you don't seem to want to take advantage of file mapping (namely, reading on demand) you can just go ahead and read the entire file into memory, and let Windows' paging take over from there. Unless there's some other aspect of the file mapping that you want to take advantage of.

Comment: @StaceyGirl i want the page to be somewhere where I'm at least somewhat guaranteed that I can read it in finite time. So, in memory, or in the paging file. But I don't want it to be on a network device.

Comment: @IInspectable Windows paging will crash me if it can't get the page, that's the point... I would have to surround every reading operation with structured exception handling... Look at what problems Sublime Merge had with that.

Comment: @Kalinovcic Then the obvious solution will be to read that page into a memory (into a private mapping). That is the only place that can guaranteed, aside from `VirtualLock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to just guarantee there will be no network access, you can read required regions to a private memory using [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) (may be done asynchronously).

Another (hacky) way is to use copy-on-write ([FILE_MAP_COPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile)) mapping and cause fake page modification. This allows you to have a contiguous memory mapping that might be easier to navigate, but with certain pages being kept in a private memory. This has disadvantage of causing increased memory pressure as OS reserves memory for the whole mapping.

Comment: It might still go to swap, but if windows can't page in from swap, your probably in trouble.

Comment: @user1937198 Yes, swap is fine... I guess this is the best that Win32 supports. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running in an account with the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege, no. That is the only way to ensure that a particular piece of memory is not paged out.